# Keeping only duplicate values by rows

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
A = c(4.3, 0.2, 3.7, 1.5, 0.5, 1.6, 2.7)
P = c(4.2, 2.1, 3.0, 2.8, 1.1, 2.3, 3.0)
T1 = c("a", "a1", "e1", "d1", "a3", "f1", "f2") 
T2 = c("a", "b1", "a1", "b2", "a3", "f1", "f3")
T3 = c("c", "c1", "e1", "b2", "k1", "a4", "f3")
T4 = c(NA, "b1", "e1", "b3", "c1", "b3", "f5")
T5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "d6", "a4", "f6")
T6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "f4",  NA, "f7") 
T7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c1")
T8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "c8")
T9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "f1")
T10= c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "k3")

df1 <- data.frame(A, P, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10)
```

I would like to delete all the unique values by rows and only keep the duplicates in each row, so I would like to get this:

```
A = c(4.3, 0.2, 3.7, 1.5, 0.5, 1.6, 2.7)
P = c(4.2, 2.1, 3.0, 2.8, 1.1, 2.3, 3.0)
T1 = c("a", NA, "e1", NA, "a3", "f1", NA) 
T2 = c("a", "b1", NA, "b2", "a3", "f1", "f3")
T3 = c(NA, NA, "e1", "b2", NA, "a4", "f3")
T4 = c(NA, "b1", "e1", NA, NA, NA, NA)
T5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "a4", NA)
T6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA) 
T7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
T8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
T9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
T10= c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

df2 <- data.frame(A, P, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10)
```

I know how to do the opposite, deleting all the duplicates, so I tried changing the coding calling for deleting the non duplicates but it only kept one record from each duplicates and also the records of the "A" and "P" columns were deleted. 
Then I tried to run the code for only the "T" type columns but then it did not even returned a data frame. Here is my first code:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) {x[!duplicated(x)] <- NA; x})))
```

and for trying to restrict the code for certain columns:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(apply(select_if(df1, grepl("T^[0-9]+$", colnames(df1)==T)), 1, function(x) {x[!duplicated(x)] <- NA; x})))
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to specify the `duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)` in order to get all values, i.e.

```
i1 <- t(apply(df1[-c(1, 2)], 1, function(i)duplicated(i)|duplicated(i, fromLast = TRUE)))
df1[-c(1, 2)][!i1] <- NA
df1
#    A   P   T1   T2   T3   T4   T5   T6   T7   T8   T9  T10
#1 4.3 4.2    a    a <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#2 0.2 2.1 <NA>   b1 <NA>   b1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3 3.7 3.0   e1 <NA>   e1   e1 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#4 1.5 2.8 <NA>   b2   b2 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#5 0.5 1.1   a3   a3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#6 1.6 2.3   f1   f1   a4 <NA>   a4 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#7 2.7 3.0 <NA>   f3   f3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```